# Unity Reference Transform not always the same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, transform

Basically I am trying to get the position of the player from an enemy script. I've checked the position from the player themselves and the position is always the same(during test I don't move the player at all). For some reason though when I get the transform location from the enemy script it returns a different number and the number isn't even the same each time. Here is a few of the cords it gives

```
(-0.5, 0.4, -6.7)
(-0.5, 0.5, -6.7)   
(-0.5, 0.6, -6.7)   
(-1.2, 0.6, -5.5)
(-1.3, 0.6, -6.7)
```

While the actual cords of the object are (-1.3, 0.6, -6.7). I've tried creating a function that gets the transform directly and then calling that from the object and the enemy and the same issue happens.

Here is the code lines that create and get the player script:

Declared in the class

```
scr_Character player;
```

In the Awake function

```
player = FindObjectOfType<scr_Character>();
```

as a note both objects have a Character Controller and a Rigid Body with a sub object holding their respective meshes.

any help would be greatly apreciated.

Edit:

It seems like the y axis slowly gets lower and lower going down by about .1 every 20 frames or so. Then every 5 frames it actually prints the right cords and then continues counting down with the wrong cords.

I made a child object that also gets the transform and it seems to have the same issue.

```
playerTrans = GetComponentInParent<Transform>();
```

Edit again:
It seems that rigid body gravity is responsible for the y value and by locking the x it stops jittering. No idea what is causing that but this does seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I don't see how do you get the reference to the player object? Use a tag for your player and search the tag.

Comment: does getting the script not actually find the object itself? The scr_Character is the main script on the player which has the function I use to get the players position:

public Vector3 getPosition()
    {
        return transform.position;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the rigid body was causing all the problems, I set it to freeze position on all axis and that seems to have stopped the problem. However it seems that it also stops any reference from getting the proper transform.position so I had to make a public function to get the Vector3 itself.